# RedisContainer keeps waiting during test [Python Testcontainers]

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, redis, testcontainers

I want to test my endpoints using `RedisContainer` from `tescontainers` but I had a problem during testing. Since it does not respond I wrote a simple code to see whether it works fine but when I start the RedisContainer it stucks at waiting stage probably that is why I had a problem during tests.

My simple code:

```
from testcontainers.redis import RedisContainer
with RedisContainer('redis:latest') as re: 
     re.start() 
     print("Hello")
     re.stop()
```

The output:

> ```
> Pulling image redis:latest
> Container started: 381b7daed7
> Waiting to be ready...`
>
> testcontainers.core.exceptions.TimeoutException: Wait time exceeded 120 sec.
>                 Method _connect, args () , kwargs {}.
>                     Exception Error 11001 connecting to localnpipe:64913. getaddrinfo failed.
> ```

I faced with the same issue with `PostgresContainer` before and solved it like in this issue:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-python/issues/108#issuecomment-660371568

Replacing host value prevented container from getting stuck:

```
class PostgresContainerX(PostgresContainer):     
      def get_connection_url(self):         
          return super().get_connection_url().replace('localnpipe', 'localhost')
```

But I don't know how to solve the problem with RedisContainer. I looked at code of [redis container](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-python/blob/master/testcontainers/redis.py) but I could not find any way to solve it. Any suggestions or comments would be great to help this issue.

Comment: Are you using Windows by any chance? What are the versions of Docker Desktop and Windows you're using?

Comment: @OlegŠelajev I'm using Windows10 and Docker Desktop 4.6.1. By the way, I was using `testcontainers` version 3.4.2 and a few days ago I saw 3.5 version came out and I tried it but I got still errors + even changing connection url to "localhost" did not work so I'm still using 3.4.2 to work with `PostgresContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can import os module and change TC_HOST to localhost on top of the file where redis container is used.

```
import os

os.environ['TC_HOST'] = 'localhost'
```

Comment: This is actually working!